# how to set byte value in vb.net above 2gb file

Tags: vb.net

I have 2gb above file that file store in file stream using byte, i got the error

> "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow."

I need to store large file above 2gb.

using this code

```
Dim fs As System.IO.FileStream
fs = File.Open(fpath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)
Dim filelen As Long = fs.Length
Dim buffer(fs.Length - 1) As Byte
fs.Read(buffer, 0, filelen)
fs.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess: you are initiating a variable array but the size of the array is over-limit, which would make sense if you are loading a file > 2 Gb to memory (why ?). Check the section "Length Limits" on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/#array-size). What you are doing sounds like an awful idea which could even cripple your computer. Instead you should implement some form of streaming, reading the file in smaller chunks.